# Template doesn't show up when wrapping it with {{#with}}?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm following the [Discover Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/) book

For some reason, the content in `edit_post.html` doesn't show up with the `{{#with post}}`:

```
<template name="postEdit">
  {{#with post}}
    <form class="main">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="url">URL</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input name="url" type="text" value="{{url}}" placeholder="Your URL"/>
        </div>
      </div>
     .
     .
     .
    </form>
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

the content of post_edit.js:

```
Template.postEdit.helpers({
  post: function() {
    return Posts.findOne(Session.get('currentPostId'));
  }
});

Template.postEdit.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var currentPostId = Session.get('currentPostId');

    var postProperties = {
      url: $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val(),
      title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
    }

    Posts.update(currentPostId, {$set: postProperties}, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        // display the error to the user
        alert(error.reason);
      } else {
        Router.go('postPage', {_id: currentPostId});
      }
    });
  },

  'click .delete': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      .
      .
      .
    }
  }
});
```

route.js:

```
this.route('postEdit', {
  path: '/posts/:_id/edit',
  data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
});
```

The template shows up if I remove the `{{#with post}}`.

I'm not sure if this is an error in the book, or whether I'm doing something wrong. I'm a Meteor beginner so I have no clue.

Any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: What is in the console if you type `Session.get("currentPostId")`?  In the code you show you are not setting it.

Comment: @user728291 I get: `Session.get("currentPostId");
undefined` Strange, I didn't skip anything in the book. What should I do now?

Comment: @user728291 maybe the book is mistaken and it should be `return Posts.findOne(Session.set('currentPostId'));` instead? Oh, wait I'm confused now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template helper `post` calls a Session variable that is never set so I think that findOne() returns a falsy value.  So {{#with post}} is correctly keeping the template from displaying.  Without the {{#with post}} your template is able to display a post from the `data` function in the router. You are calling findOne() looking for the same data twice but either method will work to get the data you want for the template.

If you want to use {{#with}} you can change your route.js to:

```
this.route('postEdit', {
  path: '/posts/:_id/edit',
  before: function() { Session.set( "currentPostId", this.params._id ); }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at the code from the book and I cannot see the with block you are referring to.

In fact, it should not be there because the data context of the template is already set by the router.

Your template helper (post) is not supposed to be there since it is both unnecessary and in fact there is no already set session variable so your get returns null as expected.

Just delete your helper and the with block and let iron router provide the data context as it already does.

Comment: Thanks! Strange, maybe mine is an old version of the book?

Comment: Hm, if you're not reading it online (perhaps from epub or pdf) than that may be true. I just checked it again online and there is no with block. But the point is, I hope you understand how the router sets the data context and why you actually don't need the post helper. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: It is at http://book.discovermeteor.com but you'll obviously need to purchase an account for that. The online version is interactive with comment discussions, git checkouts, chapter deployments, videos etc.

Comment: Old versions of the book had some bugs with iron router code, and even older versions used the now deprecated router package. So make sure you are on the most recent version.